# Only find the first match in a regex search

Tags: c#, regex

```
Regex messageServerRegex = 
    new Regex(@"([0-9\-]{10})\ ([0-9:]{8})\ \[TEXT\]\ (\[Server\])\ ([^\[]*)");

if (messageServerRegex.IsMatch(rchConsoleText))
{
    var infoMatches = messageServerRegex.Split(rchConsoleText);
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}\nTime: {1}\nType: {2}\nMessage: {3}",
    infoMatches[1], infoMatches[2], infoMatches[3], infoMatches[4]);
}
```

Here are two examples of the text we want the server to filter

> 2012-12-24 02:24:18 [TEXT] [Server] 2012-12-24 02:24:18 [TEXT] [Server] Sample text.

The result we want back from this line is:

```
Date: 2012-12-14  
Time: 02:24:18  
Type: [TEXT] [Server]  
Message: 2012-12-24 02:24:18 [TEXT] [Server] Sample text.
```

But it will respond back with:

```
Date: 2012-12-14  
Time: 02:24:18  
Type: [TEXT] [Server]  
Message: 2012-12-24 02:24:18
```

As you can see, it only shows the date and time, that's because the regex filters on that, so how do I let it only cut the date and time 1 time?

The second example works fine, which is:

> 2012-12-24 02:24:18 [TEXT] [Server] Sample text sample text sample text.

The result we want back from this line is:

```
Date: 2012-12-14  
Time: 02:24:18  
Type: [TEXT] [Server]  
Message: Sample text sample text sample text.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Split?  I think that is making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Why not use `regex.Match` or `.Matches` with named groups?

Comment: @agent-j Doesn't that resolve in the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if your input is broken into lines.  If so, it's easy to use Match.

```
     var inputs = new string[]{
        @"2012-12-24 02:24:18 [TEXT] [Server] 2012-12-24 02:24:18 [TEXT] [Server] Sample text.",
        @"2012-12-24 02:24:18 [TEXT] [Server] Sample text sample text sample text."};

     foreach(string input in inputs)
     {
        string pattern = @"([0-9\-]{10}) ([0-9:]{8}) \[TEXT\]\ (\[Server\]) (.*)";
        var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
        Console.WriteLine(
           "Date: {0}\nTime: {1}\nType: {2}\nMessage: {3}",
           match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value, match.Groups[3].Value, match.Groups[4].Value);
     }
```

If not, it gets a little tougher - instead of a `.*` it will be a `((?!something that indicates the next entry).)`

Comment: This puts me on the right path, it's almost working how I want it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The final group in your regex excludes '[' characters which causes the text portion of the line not to match if it contains a [ character. The exclusion seems unnecesary if the input represents a single log message. Try it without the exclusion, .*, and see if that works

Comment: Then I get this output: "Message: 2" :(.

Comment: Didn't notice you were using split. Try agent-js suggestion and use .match and use the capture groups from your regex

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^([0-9\-]{10})\ ([0-9:]{8})\s*\[TEXT\]\s*\[Server\]\s*(.*)
```